# How do I count number of columns in each line using vi?

Tags: vi

I have a file which is supposed to have exactly 8 columns on each line.  But apparently there are a few lines that have an extra 'tab'.  Is it possible in `vi` to search for only those lines that contain column more than 8 so that the problem can be fixed?

Comment: I tried using `awk` as follows `awk '{if(NF!=8){print $0}}'`.  The output is the lines that do not contain 3 fields.  But I dont know how to get this output in `vi` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for any line with more than 8 characters try `/^.\{8}.\+$`

#### Step by step

`/` - start a search

`^` - means "beginning of the line"

`.` - any character

`\{8}` - 8 of the preceding match (in this case... "any character")

`.` - any character

`\+` - 1 or more of the preceding match

`$` - end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `/` search:

```
/^.........
```

(that's 9 periods)